# How many state bytes will contract address variable consume in Solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I am wondering how many bytes will be if you declare Contract type in the state variable of a contract like below.

```
contract ContractA {
  // some code...
}
contract ContractB {
  ContractA contractA; // how much bytes will this state take up?
  constructor (address addr) {
    contractA = ContractA(addr);
  }
}
```

I am curious about this because 32 bytes in a single storage slot in solidity fit multiple variables into a single slot besides contract type variable.

Is it the same as the address type, 20 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In Solidity, all storage slots are 32 bytes

this is correct but that does not mean that state variables will consume 32 bytes. For example

```
uint8 public a=7 // 1 byte
uint16 public b=12 // 2 bytes
address public c=0xasdkhfk...... // 20 bytes
bool d=true //1 byte
uint64 public e=12 //8 bytes
uint256 public f=213 // 32 bytes
```

Ethereum virtual machine will pack the state variables into the slots. In the above state variables, the first 5 variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` will be placed into the first slot. as you see the order of items matters in solidity.

Based on a great answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115413/what-does-an-explicit-conversion-from-an-address-to-a-contract-type-actually-do

> In Solidity a contract variable is really just an address under the
> hood.

that means it takes up 20 bytes. The author of the answer explains the difference betweeen `address` and `contract` type. we can call the contract with the address itself, too:

> You can actually interact with code deployed at a particular address
> without having a contract variable. address has member functions like
> .call() for example. These functions are a low-level EVM way to make
> an external call. At this level functions do not really exist. You
> specify some call data to be sent to that code and receive back a
> piece of return data.

[Member of address type](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types)

Here why do we use `contract` type:

> Solidity's contract types are an abstraction to make that external
> code look more like classes you may be familiar with from other
> languages. Classes can have methods, and in Solidity the compiler
> simulates this by having the bytecode expect a function ID (selector)
> in the first 4 bytes of call data and do different things based on
> which ID was sent. In particular the ID determines how to interpret
> the data that follows it (i.e. the parameters).
>
> Instead of using the low-level .call() on an address and manually
> constructing the right call data, you can just call an external
> function on a contract, and the compiler will convert that for you to
> a low-level call in the bytecode it generates. To do this, however, it
> needs to know the address of that contract. You can give it this
> information by casting the address to the contract type. For
> convenience, you can store the result of such a cast in a contract
> variable instead of having to cast it every time.

Answer (score 2):

In Solidity, [all storage slots are 32 bytes](https://kubertu.com/blog/solidity-storage-in-depth/) and this is how much state most variable declarations will consume.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But how much specifically contract type variable consume? like uint8 will use 1byte so 32 of them can be stored into a single slot (although it will consume more gas)

Comment: It depends on your struct definition. There wasn't one in your question so it is not possible to tell. Most likely 32 bytes.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand why struct matters? I think contract types take up 20bytes like address type as @Yilmaz explained. Do you have different answers?

Comment: In your example code there are no other variables so it will consume 32 bytes