# what type of variable should i use to store contracts in soldity

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

so, First, I imported the simpleStorage contract and then wrote this function createNeewContracts() to push the contract address into an array
everything was going smooth and I got an idea
"why not just use a struct of two variables 1. string (name of the contract owner) and 2. address (of the contract the owner owns) and i can then have name of owner and his contract as a struct stored in an array named contractAndThereArray"
I could have used mapping but I used struct and array to do the work

I ran into a problem it say

"TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from contract SimpleStorage1 to address requested."

here is the code:-

```
contract StorageFactory{
    // SimpleStorage public simpleStorage;
    struct ownerAndThereContracts {
        string name;
        address nf;

    }
    ownerAndThereContracts[] public saveYourContracts;
    SimpleStorage1[] public x;
    // mapping(string => address) y;
    uint256 counter;
    function createNewContracts() public {
        SimpleStorage1 simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage1();  
        x.push(simpleStorage);
        // address j = simpleStorage;
    }
        
        function refering(string memory _name) public {
            counter++;
        SimpleStorage1 simpleStorage2 = SimpleStorage1(x[counter]);
        saveYourContracts.push(ownerAndThereContracts(_name,simpleStorage2)); //  the error occurs here it says simpleStorage2 is not address but contract 

        }




    

}
```

The problem is with the function referring where i tried to refer the address of a contract with the owners name but seems there is a problem

Please,if someone can explain it. Please explain I need your help guys

i've been tried to solve it for hours now but nothing seems to fit

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get into your logic and fixed your contract and solve your mistake. Specifically, your error states that you cannot insert an instance of a contract into a field with datatype address. In order to solve this problem you need to cast the contract instance in address datatype. You can see the contract in the following lines, I have also inserted some notes to let you understand what I have changed:

```
// SDPX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./SimpleStorage1.sol";

contract StorageFactory{
    uint256 counter;

    struct ownerAndThereContracts{
        string name;
        address nf; // NOTE: I assume that it's the SimpleStorage address
    }

    ownerAndThereContracts[] public saveYourContracts;
    SimpleStorage1[] public x;

    function createNewContracts() public {
        SimpleStorage1 simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage1();  
        x.push(simpleStorage);
    }

    function refering(string memory _name) public {
        // NOTE: I assume that when creating new contract, then you must refering it directly to an owner.
        //       In this case, I retrieve the length of array in details the last element index.  
        counter = x.length-1;
        SimpleStorage1 simpleStorage2 = SimpleStorage1(x[counter]);
        // NOTE: You must cast your contract instance to an address for put it into your struct (because the datatype is 'address')
        saveYourContracts.push(ownerAndThereContracts(_name,address(simpleStorage2)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok first i fixed your code, you are missing 2 casting, first to address and then to a paybale address.

Here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.15;

contract SimpleStorage1{

}

contract StorageFactory{
    // SimpleStorage public simpleStorage;
    struct ownerAndThereContracts {
        string name;
        address nf;

    }
    ownerAndThereContracts[] public saveYourContracts;
    SimpleStorage1[] public x;
    // mapping(string => address) y;
    uint256 counter;
    function createNewContracts() public {
        SimpleStorage1 simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage1();  
        x.push(simpleStorage);
        // address j = simpleStorage;
    }
        
        function refering(string memory _name) public {
            counter++;
        SimpleStorage1 simpleStorage2 = SimpleStorage1(x[counter]);
        address  simpleStorage2Address = address(simpleStorage2); //first cast to address
        address payable _finalCast = payable(simpleStorage2Address); // then cast to payable address
        saveYourContracts.push(ownerAndThereContracts(_name, _finalCast));

    }
```

But you should know that this is a very costy contract, you should take out all the process of saving the contract to a environment like c or java and only create the contract through solidity so the objects on memory wont cost you.

Anyway good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From docs: [contract-types](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/types.html#contract-types)

> Explicit conversion to and from the address payable type is only
> possible if the contract type has a receive or payable fallback
> function. The conversion is still performed using address(x). If the
> contract type does not have a receive or payable fallback function,
> the conversion to address payable can be done using
> payable(address(x))

I explained here [contract-type vs address type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72752086/how-many-state-bytes-will-contract-address-variable-consume-in-solidity/72763945#72763945)

> In Solidity a contract variable is really just an address under the
> hood.